# Android file exists problems

Tags: android, file, file-exists

When i make File file = new File(etc..) i actuly created that file on SD card? Iam bit confused because everytime my condition is true and program jumps in if tree but in that time there is no file on SD card...

```
    String filename = "pictures.data";
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File dir = new File(root + "/courier/saved/");
    File file = new File(dir,filename);

    if (file.exists())
        // program jumps here
    else{

    }
```

Comment: Why use `toString()` method? You can use `File.getPath()` that returns a String.

Comment: PRint the variable root. The getExternalStorageDirectory() does not reliably gives sd card location (I have seen different devices behave differently for this). Once you confirm that the root variable is indeed pointing to external SD card, then you can dig further

Comment: /storage/sdcard0 is my externalstorage so /storage/sdcard0/courier/saved/ is added to path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so you can see the file in a dir /courier/saved/. Anyway here's my answer

```
String filename = "pictures.data";
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File dir = new File(root + "/courier/saved/");
File file = new File(dir,filename);
file.mkdirs();
if (file.exists())
    // program now stops here
else{

}
```

Best would be to create the dir beforehand maybe, But this creates it on the fly

Comment: In next step iam checking if file doesnt exist then i have condition if (!dir.exists()) { dir.mkdirs();} but if file exists then read from file and then save it again...

Comment: btw, Welcome to Stackoverflow. That is a new question and you must post it as that. During the creation of your new question you will be presented with many existing answers, try it. And press Accept on my Answer to close the question. If you think my Answered solved this question press Accept and upvote if your happy